# Creating a sprite sheet from existing sprite sheets while game is running?

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I've been making a 2D game with XNA that will have several unique enemies. I have no trouble drawing separate sprites to the screen, one over the other to make no two enemies alike, but I think it might be more efficient if instead of drawing a dozen sprites per enemy, I somehow merged those sprites into one sprite sheet.

If I have lots and lots of these enemies on the screen, will I improve performance by a worthy amount if I do merge? And is there a simple way for me to create new sprite sheets in this way, or is the answer quite fiddly?

Comment: This probably isn't a worthwhile optimisation - unless you've measured and identified the performance bottleneck. It's a *lot* of work for very little gain. Individual sprites within a batch are quite cheap (if you avoid texture changes with a sprite-sheet - [more info](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9289/288)).

Comment: For my own clarification, are you asking to create sprite sheets dynamically at run time? Why not just create the sprite sheet prior to compilation and load it in as part of the normal content pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

It can be faster to draw one sprite instead of several. However, I would only recommend this, if you have performance problems. Drawing sprites is quite fast with the `SpriteBatch`. It has the nice feature to group draw calls of the same texture, which makes it pretty fast. If you create a separate texture for each enemy, you can loose this feature, which could result in a performance loss. Creating one large sprite sheet can be better, if the sheet does not get too large.

To create such a sheet, you have to create a texture / render target and render to it. [Here](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php) is how to do it with XNA.